# How do you validate uniqueness of a pair of ids in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, model, unique-constraint

Suppose the following DB migration in Ruby:

```
    create_table :question_votes do |t|
      t.integer :user_id
      t.integer :question_id
      t.integer :vote

      t.timestamps
    end
```

Suppose further that I wish the rows in the DB contain unique (user_id, question_id) pairs.  What is the right dust to put in the model to accomplish that?

```
validates_uniqueness_of :user_id, :question_id
```

seems to simply make rows unique by user id, and unique by question id, instead of unique by the pair.

Comment: Note: I haven't gone back to this project, so I haven't had time to test the answers below. If someone posts an answer that has the shortest possible test that demonstrates an answer, and the output of that test, I will accept that answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 95):

```
validates_uniqueness_of :user_id, :scope => [:question_id]
```

if you needed to include another column (or more), you can add that to the scope as well.  Example:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :user_id, :scope => [:question_id, :some_third_column]
```

Comment: should the value be in square brackets, not curly braces?

Comment: @gwho **Square brackets** denote an **array, a sequence of values**. **Curly braces** denote a **hash, a set of key-value pairs**. We're not specifying keys here, only values. I understand it's kinda late and you probably know it already, but it might help out beginners coming here :)

Comment: Oh it's not a scope lambda.

Comment: If you prefer the `validates` syntax: `validates :user_id, uniqueness: { scope: [:question_id] }`

Comment: Will this validation only fail when  `user_id and question_id` both are same?

Answer (score 27):

If using mysql, you can do it in the database using a unique index. It's something like:

```
add_index :question_votes, [:question_id, :user_id], :unique => true
```

This is going to raise an exception when you try to save a doubled-up combination of question_id/user_id, so you'll have to experiment and figure out which exception to catch and handle.

Comment: Yes, but the exception don't help when you want just an error message.

Answer (score 20):

The best way is to use both, since rails isn't 100% reliable when uniqueness validation come thru.

You can use:

```
  validates :user_id, uniqueness: { scope: :question_id }
```

and to be 100% on the safe side, add this validation on your db (MySQL ex)

```
  add_index :question_votes, [:user_id, :question_id], unique: true
```

and then you can handle in your controller using:

```
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique
```

So now you are 100% secure that you won't have a duplicated value :)

Comment: This should be the best answer, validates alone is not enough! See this article for the details why: https://robots.thoughtbot.com/the-perils-of-uniqueness-validations

Comment: Best response, thanks for including everything needed!

Answer (score 15):

From [RailsGuides](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#uniqueness). `validates` works too:

```
class QuestionVote < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :user_id, :uniqueness => { :scope => :question_id }
end
```

Answer (score 10):

Except for writing your own validate method, the best you could do with `validates_uniqueness_of` is this:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :user_id, :scope => "question_id"
```

This will check that the user_id is unique within all rows with the same question_id as the record you are attempting to insert.

**But that's not what you want**.

I believe you're looking for the combination of `:user_id` and `:question_id` to be unique across the database.

In that case you need to do two things:

1. Write your own validate method.
2. Create a constraint in the database
   because there's still a chance that
   your app will process two records at
   the same time.

Comment: What if I do

<pre>
validate_uniqueness_of :user_id, :scope => :question_id
validate_uniqueness_of :question_id, :scope => :user_id
</pre>

Is that enough?

Comment: I'm not seeing the difference between `validates_uniqueness_of` using `scope` and the combination being unique.  Can you provide an example of how they would differ?

Answer (score 2):

When you are creating a new record, that doesn't work because the `id` of your parent model doesn't exist still at moment of validations.

This should to work for you.

```
class B < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :ab
  has_many :a, :through => :ab
end

class AB < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :b
  belongs_to :a
end

class A < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :ab
  has_many :b, :through => :ab

  after_validation :validate_uniqueness_b

  private
  def validate_uniqueness_b
    b_ids = ab.map(&:b_id)
    unless b_ids.uniq.length.eql? b_ids.length
      errors.add(:db, message: "no repeat b's")
    end
  end
end
```

In the above code I get all `b_id` of collection of parameters, then compare if the length between the unique values and obtained b_id are equals.
If are equals means that there are not repeat `b_id`.

**Note: don't forget to add unique in your database's columns**.