# How do I validate two fields for uniqueness

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to validate the uniqueness of two fields in an object (row) before I add them.  Employee_id and area_id are the two fields in my emp_area table.  There can be multiple records with the same employee_id and multiple records with the same area_id, but no two records can have the same employee_id and the same area_id.  This is sort of like two fields making up a primary-key or unique-key.

How can I do this.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you validate uniqueness of a pair of ids in Ruby on Rails?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/923796/how-do-you-validate-uniqueness-of-a-pair-of-ids-in-ruby-on-rails)

Answer (score 99):

what about this solution [Validate combined values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2533502/rails-3-validate-combined-values)

```
validates :employee_id, uniqueness: { scope: :area_id }
```

Comment: This seems to be preferred over `validates_uniqueness_of` as it allows you set multiple validations on the same form, e.g. `presence: true`.

Comment: For correct highlight of the error messages I created also

   validates :area_id, uniqueness: { scope: employee_id }

Answer (score 69):

```
validates_uniqueness_of :employee_id, :scope => :area_id
```