# Rails 3: Validate combined values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, validates-uniqueness-of, database-integrity

In Rails 2.x you can use validations to make sure you have a unique combined value like this:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :husband, :scope => :wife
```

In the corresponding migration it could look like this:

```
add_index :family, [:husband, :wife], :unique => true
```

This would make sure the husband/wife combination is unique in the database. Now, in Rails 3 the validation syntax changed and the scope attribute seems to be gone. It now looks like:

```
validates :husband, :presence => true
```

Any idea how I can achieve the combined validation in Rails 3? The Rails 2.x validations still work in Rails 3 so I can still use the first example but it looks so "old", are there better ways?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Bear with me. The way the validates method in ActiveModel works is to look for a Validator.

`:presence => true` looks for `PresenceValidator` and passes the options: `true` to the validator's initializer.

I think you want

```
validates :husband, :presence => true, :uniqueness => {:scope => :wife}
```

(The uniqueness validator is actually part of ActiveRecord, not ActiveModel. It's really interesting how the developers set this up. It's quite elegant.)

Comment: This sounds awesome and clean and all but... it doesn't work in my sample 'one model project' I tried. Did you guys did anything special? I used 2 strings and also tried with 2 integers but the validations just pass.

Comment: I'm using `validates :contents, :presence => true, :uniqueness => {:scope => :comment_thread_id, :message => "has been said already, please add something meaningful"}`

Comment: Oops, so sorry, my bad. I was trying the wrong test, it does work. Thank you for the super fast and excellent answer!

Comment: I know this is an old(ish) question, but I was just trying this same method and couldn't get it to work like this, I had to do two separate validation statements: validates :husband, :presence => true and validates :husband_id, :uniqueness => {:scope => :wife_id}

Comment: @fishwebby I'm using this `validates :visibility, :presence => true, :inclusion => { :in => VISIBILITIES }` with rails 3.0.3 and I haven't encountered that problem.

Comment: @epochwolf It's the :uniqueness bit that I couldn't get to work - I'm also on Rails 3.0.3 - as I got it to work with two separate validation statements I didn't investigate it any further.