# Validate uniqueness of two columns

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I am trying to validate that two columns are unique in my User model.  I've searched Google and from what I understand the following code will not work:

```
validates :login, :uniqueness=>true
validates :email, :uniqueness=>true
```

In my case doing that will validate the uniqueness of email, but will not validate the uniqueness of login.  I set that login must be unique on the database.  However, all that will do is generate a runtime error if it already exists.  I don't want that error in production because it would result in a 500 internal server error, which the user would not understand.

Any ideas on how I could validate the uniqueness of both of these fields?

**Authentication Used:**

- CanCan
- Devise
- Devise Invitable

**Update:**

From what I can tell the problem is being caused by Devise, specifically the validatable module, which validate email and password.

**Update 2:**

Removing the validatable module from Devise will result in neither checking for uniqueness.

**Update 3:**

It appears that devise is not causing the problem.  Rather, a gem called Devise Invitable is.  Removing this gem results in the validation being triggered.  It also appears that this gem tries to force validations of the email field.  It makes sense due to the nature of this gem, but  shouldn't be blocking.

Comment: Are you using an authentication gem? If so, that might be catching the validation. This should work, so there's a conflict upstream somewhere.

Comment: @JohnMetta I'm using CanCan with Devise

Comment: what you describe should work. but you could also try "validates_uniqueness_of :login, :email" - how does this runtime error look like? which version of rails are you using ?

Comment: @frankblizzard the runntime error states:  ```ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique in UsersController#create``` and I am using Rails 3.2.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the devise_invitable gem.  In the devise initializer I had to set

```
  config.validate_on_invite = true
```

to make sure the validations were executed, the default is false. I also had to remove the devise validatable module.

Answer (score 10):

Should be able to do it with `scope`, adding to the default validation by devise.

For Rails 3 versions :

```
validates :email, :uniqueness => {:scope => :login}
```

Ref:

- [rails 3 validation on uniqueness on multiple attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3276110/rails-3-validation-on-uniqueness-on-multiple-attributes)
- [How do I validate two fields for uniqueness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1633297/how-do-i-validate-two-fields-for-uniqueness)
- [API doc for validates_uniqueness_of](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_uniqueness_of)

Comment: When I try this solution I get ```rescue in block in validates': Unknown
 validator: 'ScopeValidator' (ArgumentError)``` when trying to start the rails server.

Comment: Verified that I too got the same error. My bad; I had given the Rails 2 version of the solution. I updated the answer with the Rails 3 version of the solution. Verified it works on my side. The order of attributes is important. The solution I gave validates the uniqueness of new email in combination with existing logins.

Comment: While your solution may be valid.  I think the underlying problem comes from devise_invitable, removal of this gem result in the right behavior but cripples some of the functionality that is required for the application (being what that gem is suppose to do).

Comment: I doubt devise_invitable functionality would interfere with the validations part. I suggest trying the scoped validation and verify that email & login combination can be set as unique.

Comment: The two original validations work after config.validate_on_invite = true.  If not then it does not work.  I think it is because instead of calling .save .invite!(params) is called to send an email to the user and bypass the password validation.

Answer (score 0):

The code works perfectly fine on the Rails 3.2.8..I have tested on it...

maybe there are some problems with your gems...