# Validate uniqueness of a value for two columns Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

`email` and `new_email` are two distinct columns. Every email should be unique, so if an email is added into either column it cannot already exist in either `email` or `new_email` columns.

Back story: I create the primary `email` for activated accounts and have a second `new_email` for when a user decides to change their email address but has not yet validated the new one via an email confirmation.

Most SO searches gave the `scope` [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12978516/validate-uniqueness-of-two-columns):

I've tried `validates :email, uniqueness: {scope: :new_email}` and `validates :new_email, uniqueness: {scope: :email}` however I'm pretty sure this functionality acts to create a new key among the `email1, email2` pair which is not the desired effect.

Currently I'm judging the validity of my code with the following two test cases (which are failing)

```
test "new_email should not match old email" do
  @user.new_email = @user.email
  assert_not @user.valid?
end

test "new_email addresses should be unique" do
  duplicate_user = @user.dup
  duplicate_user.new_email = @user.email.upcase
  duplicate_user.email = @user.email + "z"
  @user.save
  assert_not duplicate_user.valid?
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scope's not going to cut it... it's really there to make sure that `mail` is unique amongst all records that might share the same `new_mail` and won't catch uniqueness for different `new_email` values, nor will it compare the values across the two columns.

Use standard 'uniqueness' to ensure there's no duplication within the column.

Then you'll need to create a custom validation for cross column...

```
validate :emails_unique

def emails_unique
  found_user = User.find_by(new_email: email) 
  errors.add(:email, "email is someone's new email") if found_user
  return unless new_email
  found_user = User.find_by(email: new_email) 
  errors.add(:new_email, "new email is someone's regular email") if found_user
end
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you for the explanation.

Comment: Oddly, I had to add `.downcase` in the `emails_unique` method since the built in one had a small loophole for case sensitivity amongst emails.

Comment: @AlexeiDarmin if you want the comparison to be case-insensitive, you can use `LIKE` (in MySQL) or `ILIKE` (in PostgreSQL)

Answer (score 0):

I think you really just want to write a custom validator, something like this:

```
validate :emails_are_unique

def emails_are_unique
  if email == new_email
    errors.add(:base, 'Your new email can not match your old email')
  end
end
```

Which will do what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

`validates :email, uniqueness: {scope: :new_email}` will ensure that `email` is unique among all records with the same value for `new_email`. This is not what you want.

You'll have to write a custom validation function, e.g.:

```
def validate_email_and_new_email_unique
  if email && self.class.exists?("email = :email OR new_email = :email", email: email)
    errors.add :email, "must be unique"
  end
  if new_email && self.class.exists?("email = :email OR new_email = :email", email: new_email)
    errors.add :new_email, "must be unique"
  end
end
```