# Unique symmetrical pairs validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I created a scaffold in ror in order to contain some relations between elements

```
+----------------------+
| left | right | score |
+----------------------+
```

So, if I have an entry `a, b, 10`, it means the relation from `a` to `b` is 10. But as left and right, represents `fk's` of the same kind of entity, we can conclude that the relation from `b` to `a` is also 10.

Doing something like `validates_uniqueness_of :left, :scope => [:right]` will not prevent the pair from appearing reverted in the table like so : `b, a, 10`

I suppose something like :

```
validates_uniqueness_of :left, :scope => [:right]
validates_uniqueness_of :right, :scope => [:left]
```

could do the trick, but is there a cleaner or more appropriate way to validate the uniqueness of pairs symmetrically ?

Once this is answered, the job is almost done.

How do I prevent the same value of appearing on both columns ?

eg. Such an entry should not be allowed : `a, a, 15`

Thanks for your consideration.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you validate uniqueness of a pair of ids in Ruby on Rails?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/923796/how-do-you-validate-uniqueness-of-a-pair-of-ids-in-ruby-on-rails)

Comment: @infused I don't see what's in the dup target which isn't already in the question. Also, it doesn't handle left and right being swapped.

Answer (score 0):

There might be a validation specific to your needs. I don't know.

If not, consider using a [custom validation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#performing-custom-validations)

```
class MyValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
  def validate(record)
    unless record.name.starts_with? 'X'
      record.errors[:name] << 'Need a name starting with X please!'
    end
  end
end

class Person
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  validates_with MyValidator
end
```